# Integral of a discontinuous function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Define
> $$
>  f(x)=\begin{cases} 
>       0 & x=\frac{n}{n+1}, n\in \mathbb{N} \\
>       1 & \text{elsewhere} 
>    \end{cases}
> $$
> Find $$\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

One could argue geometrically that $f(x)=1$ occurs more frequently than $f(x)=0$, so the area must tend to $1\times1=1$

How do I solve this mathematically(rigorously)?

I tried to define the area as a Riemann sum, but failed miserably.

Comment: What is ${\mathbb I}^+$ ?

Comment: @Gribouillis positive integers. I removed the formatting now.

Comment: What do you know about the integrals? In Lebesgue integration, $f(x) = 1$ almost everywhere, so $\int f dx = \int 1 dx$

Comment: @Gribouillis sorry, I don't know much about Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: Discontinuities of measure zero do not contribute to the Riemann integral.

Comment: @ParasKhosla yes, it doesn't. However I'm not able to write the elsewhere definition as a Riemann sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be a positive integer. The interval $B_N = [0, 1-\frac{1}{N}]$ contains $N$ points of the form $\frac{n}{n+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$. Let us partition $[0, 1]$ by partitioning $B_N$ in $N^2$ intervals of equal lengths and the last interval of the partition is $[1 - \frac{1}{N}, 1]$. Let $L_N$ and $U_N$ be the lower and upper Darboux sums of $f$ for this partition of $[0,1]$. Then
\begin{equation}
1 -\frac{2N}{N^2}-\frac{1}{N}\le L_N \le U_N\le 1
\end{equation}
It follows that $\int_0^1 f(x) d x = 1$ by letting $N\to\infty$.